# Android QuickContactBadge with letters like Android Lollipop

Tags: android, image, list, listview, android-contacts

I have a list of contacts and I want to show in each contact's QuickContactBadge the first letter of his name. 
Can I create the images in runtime?

This is like Android Lollipop, where contacts and dialer uses QuickContactBadge with letters:

[image: Android Lollipop screenshot]

Comment: https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable

Answer (score 10):

I use a function to generate these images.

```
public static Bitmap generateCircleBitmap(Context context, int circleColor, float diameterDP, String text){
    final int textColor = 0xffffffff;

    DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    float diameterPixels = diameterDP * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    float radiusPixels = diameterPixels/2;

    // Create the bitmap
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) diameterPixels, (int) diameterPixels,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    // Create the canvas to draw on
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // Draw the circle
    final Paint paintC = new Paint();
    paintC.setAntiAlias(true);
    paintC.setColor(circleColor);
    canvas.drawCircle(radiusPixels, radiusPixels, radiusPixels, paintC);

    // Draw the text
    if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
        final Paint paintT = new Paint();
        paintT.setColor(textColor);
        paintT.setAntiAlias(true);
        paintT.setTextSize(radiusPixels * 2);
        Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
        paintT.setTypeface(typeFace);
        final Rect textBounds = new Rect();
        paintT.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textBounds);
        canvas.drawText(text, radiusPixels - textBounds.exactCenterX(), radiusPixels - textBounds.exactCenterY(), paintT);
    }

    return output;
}
```

I pass the contact's name into the following getMaterialColor function to select a color.

```
private static List<Integer> materialColors = Arrays.asList(
        0xffe57373,
        0xfff06292,
        0xffba68c8,
        0xff9575cd,
        0xff7986cb,
        0xff64b5f6,
        0xff4fc3f7,
        0xff4dd0e1,
        0xff4db6ac,
        0xff81c784,
        0xffaed581,
        0xffff8a65,
        0xffd4e157,
        0xffffd54f,
        0xffffb74d,
        0xffa1887f,
        0xff90a4ae
);

public static int getMaterialColor(Object key) {
    return material.get(Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % materialColors.size());
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Helped me, thanks. For who will use this code. Be careful with "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf". It is not available to API 16 and below. So, you need to add manually.