# Rounded QuickContactBadge with text

Tags: java, android, quickcontactbadge

I have a `listview` with a `QuickContactBadge` and then the contact's name. The problem is the badge is a square, and if the contact does not have an image, then it is just blank. I want a circular picture or just the first initial of the contacts like in android lollipop:

[image: Contacts]

I tried the solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082367/android-quickcontactbadge-with-letters-like-android-lollipop) question, but I couldn't get it to work. Maybe I just implemented it wrong? This is what I have:

ContactsTab.java:

```
public class ContactsTab extends ListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private CustomAdapter mAdapter;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private String currentQuery;
    private int mIdColumn;
    private int mLookupKeyColumn;
    private Uri mContactUri;
    private QuickContactBadge mBadge;
    private static final String[] PROJECTION = {
            Contacts._ID,
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
            Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI,
            Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
    };
    private static final String[] FROM = { Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY };
    private static final int[] TO = { R.id.badge, R.id.contact_text };
    private static final String SELECTION = "(" + Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = 1) AND (" + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " != 0 )";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.contacts_list_item, null, FROM, TO, 0)
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        getListView().setDivider(null);
        getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Uri contentUri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                contentUri,
                PROJECTION,
                SELECTION,
                null,
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " ASC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private Cursor _cursor;
    private Context _context;
    private String[] _from;
    private int[] _to;
    private QuickContactBadge badge;
    private String lookUpKey;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
        _cursor = c;
        _context = context;
        _from = from;
        _to = to;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        int id = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID);

        lookUpKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY));


        badge = (QuickContactBadge) view.findViewById(R.id.badge);
        badge.assignContactUri(ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(id, lookUpKey));
        badge.setImageBitmap(generateCircleBitmap(R.color.accent, 42, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY.substring(0,1)));
    }

    public static Bitmap generateCircleBitmap(int circleColor, float diameterDP, String text){
        final int textColor = 0xffffffff;

        DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
        float diameterPixels = diameterDP * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
        float radiusPixels = diameterPixels/2;

        // Create the bitmap
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) diameterPixels, (int) diameterPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        // Create the canvas to draw on
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

        // Draw the circle
        final Paint paintC = new Paint();
        paintC.setAntiAlias(true);
        paintC.setColor(circleColor);
        canvas.drawCircle(radiusPixels, radiusPixels, radiusPixels, paintC);

        // Draw the text
        if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
            final Paint paintT = new Paint();
            paintT.setColor(textColor);
            paintT.setAntiAlias(true);
            paintT.setTextSize(radiusPixels * 2);
            paintT.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
            final Rect textBounds = new Rect();
            paintT.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textBounds);
            canvas.drawText(text, radiusPixels - textBounds.exactCenterX(), radiusPixels - textBounds.exactCenterY(), paintT);
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom drawable and you can do it

file : drawable/contact_badge_round.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">

    <size android:width="32dp" android:height="32dp"/>

    <gradient android:centerColor="#123456"
              android:startColor="#123456"
              android:endColor="#123456"
        />

</shape>
```

then in your layout create a Button and set the background as contact_badge_round

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/roundContact"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:text="A"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/background_new_entity_symbol"
       />
```

Done cheers!

Comment: A `QuickContactBadge` is declared by `<QuickContactBadge>` in xml, but I still tried setting `android:background` to my drawable and it set the backgound to the contacts that don't have thumbnails, but it doesn't crop the iamges of contacts. Also how would I set the text?

Comment: I tried the same i didnt find the solution. So i tried this custom way that is homogenous towards all the platforms.